# Files and Directories using Python

Tags: python, file-io

I was doing a practice problem where I have to create my own directory and put files into it using Python but I kept getting an error. I can post my code and the error message below.

Code:

```
import os

def new_directory(directory, filename):
  # Before creating a new directory, check to see if it already exists
  if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)

  # Create the new file inside of the new directory
  os.chdir(directory)
  with open(filename, "w") as file:
    pass

  # Return the list of files in the new directory
  return os.listdir(directory)

print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
```

Error Message:

```
Error on line 16:
    print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
Error on line 14:
    return os.listdir(directory)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PythonPrograms'
```

Comment: Try to remove `os.chdir(directory)`.

Comment: or `os.listdir('.')`

Answer (score 0):

```
os.chdir(directory)
```

This line puts you inside of the directory that you just created. When you try to reference the folder later, you can't see it because you're inside of it.

The simplest fix is just to go back up a directory after adding the file:
with

```
open(filename, "w") as file:
    pass

os.chdir("..")  # Go back up to the parent

return os.listdir(directory)
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments, just construct the path to avoid the need for the initial `chdir` call in the first place.

Comment: The simplest fix is deleting useless active directory change, isn't it?

Comment: @OlvinRoght He goes into the directory and creates an empty file in it, so it presumably isn't useless. Of course, he could just construct the path given to `open` instead of navigating, but that's besides the point here.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I added a note at the bottom though.

Comment: Thank you for your help